# How to select a subset of file based on ids in other file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have two files, where I want to just select the subset of .gtf files for the ids that exist in other file.
I use the grep function, but the output is empty.

```
grep -F Transcript_names2.txt  gencode.v30.annotation.gtf > selected_genes
```

Here how does .gtf file looks like:

```
##provider: GENCODE
##contact: gencode-help@ebi.ac.uk
##format: gtf
##date: 2019-03-28
chr1    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  11869   14409   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    11869   12227   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00002234944.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12721   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00003582793.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   14409   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456329.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; exon_number 3; exon_id "ENSE00002312635.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
```

and here is how Transcript_names2.txt looks like:

```
"ENST00000456328.2"
"ENST00000456329.2"
```

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man grep` is a good read.

Use `-F` to treat expressions as fixed strings. (Not Regex)

Use `-f` to source a file from which to read patterns.

They're not exclusive:

```
grep -Ff Transcript_names2.txt gencode.v30.annotation.gtf > selected_genes
```

---

New requirement: Speed. Try playing with different `-P` values; it's the number of threads.

```
xargs -I{} -P4 grep -F {} gencode.v30.annotation.gtf < Transcript_names2.txt
```

Comment: I will, but it takes a long time to get finish it for large file. Is there any multi core processes for grep?

Comment: @user2806363 see `xargs` above

Comment: where is the output of it? How do you specify the output file then?

Comment: @vintnes, How do you specify the output? Don't think that I need to have fF?

Comment: @user2806363 add `> selected_genes` to the end. The second solution uses xargs instead of -file in order to run expressions in parallel. You could also try `-P$(wc -l Transcript_names2.txt)` to run as many threads as you have patterns, but this may actually be less efficient than just a few threads.

Answer (score 0):

`vim Transcript_names2.txt`
`:set ff=unix`
This is a common problem when Windows file is imported to Linux.
The format of `.txt` file you copied from Windows is `dos` in Linux, so you need to change it into `unix`.